# Out of memory exception when writing a large file (300MB) to memory stream

Tags: c#, .net, out-of-memory, httpwebrequest

I'm getting an Out of Memory Exception when using `Http.Post` of a large file. I'm getting this exception when I tried to write the filestream data to the memory stream.

Comment: You're dealing with address space fragmentation.  300 MB is pretty hard to come by when your program has been running for while.  A 64-bit operating system is the trivial solution.

Answer (score 2):

Obviously putting 300mb of data into memory is causing the CLR to reach its maximum memory footprint. Have you considered writing the file to some other kind of stream to avoid having it all in memory at the same time? Perhaps you could write the file directly to disk, and then process the file in chunks afterward, rather than loading the whole thing into memory at the same time.

Comment: Yes, keep it simple. Although 300MB is still some way from the 2GB ceiling (CLR/32). It depends on what else is going on.

Comment: The thing is, i'm posting the file to a web service using HttpWebRequest post method, so i'm keeping it in memory stream.

Comment: @Cipriyan: So this is client-side code that's loading a file into memory before uploading it to a web server? Have you considered using WebClient.UploadFile? http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.net.webclient.uploadfile(VS.80).aspx

Answer (score 1):

None of the above answers work for me, this one does the job:

http://blogs.msdn.com/b/johan/archive/2006/11/15/are-you-getting-outofmemoryexceptions-when-uploading-large-files.aspx

These lines are the key:

```
    HttpWebRequest wr = (HttpWebRequest)WebRequest.Create(yourUri);
    wr.KeepAlive = false;
    wr.Timeout = System.Threading.Timeout.Infinite;
    wr.ProtocolVersion = HttpVersion.Version10;
```

And here:

```
wr.AllowWriteStreamBuffering = false;
```

Hope this can help someone out there.

Answer (score 0):

Set HttpWebRequest.AllowWriteStreamBuffering=false. This will cause HWR to send the data immediately, instead of buffering it in memory.